# Interlaced binomial expansion

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

For $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n < 1$ let
$$f(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n) = \sum_{k_1,k_2,...,k_n = 1}^\infty \frac{(k_1 + k_2)!}{k_1! k_2!} \frac{(k_2 + k_3)!}{k_2! k_3!}\ldots \frac{(k_{n-1} + k_{n})!}{k_{n-1}! k_{n}!} a_1^{k_1} a_2^{k_2} \ldots a_n^{k_n}$$
Any idea how to attack this problem? At least for $n=3$...

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: If you are interested in getting simple rational expressions for $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$, I would change the lower bound in the sum to 0 first.

Comment: Fedor: finding explicit rational expressions.